# Polynomial functions in python

Tags: python, polynomials

I am very new in writing Python code. I have to represent polynomial like this,

```
4x^230+7x^96+1

testP = [[4,512],[7,256],[1,0]]

def printPoly2(P):
    for i in range(len(P)):
        if P[i] != 0:
            print("%s x^%s + "%(P[i], i)),
            print

printPoly2(testP)
```

but my answer is not correct. I need help on this.

Comment: I'm not making the connection between your opening example polynomial, and your representation of it as a list of lists. Should testP not be:    [[4,230],[7,96],[1,0]] ?

Comment: I guess it should.
But P in your method is a list of lists. So P[i] returns a list and you compare it to != 0 which makes no sense.

Comment: Unpacking the list of lists as follows should yield the results I think the OP is looking for 2 changes, first the *if* clause could be:            if len(P[i]) != 0
And secondly, the following print statement as     print("%s x^%s + "%(P[i][0], P[i][1])),

Comment: Sorry, testP should be like this, testP = [[4,512],[7,256],[1,0]]

Comment: Please mark my answer as solving (if so). ty

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the print statement. By writing:

```
print("%s x^%s + "%(P[i], i))
```

You are actually printing the entire tuple. For example, `P[0]` equals the entire list `[4, 512]`. So in directly printing `P[i]` you're just printing the entire sublist.

Instead, you want to print each element in the sublist.

```
print("%s x^%s" % (P[i][0], P[i][1]))
```

Additionally, your solution as-is will print each part of the answer on a separate line. To fix this you have a couple options, but here's one that doesn't depend on the python version you have. Basically, you create a string that represents your result, and keep building on it as you go through the loop. Then at the very end of the function, you print that string.

```
result = '' # initialize an empty string before your loop
```

Then inside your loop replace the print call with:

```
result = "%s + %s x^%s" % (result, P[i][0], P[i][1]
```

And at the very end of the function you can print the string.

```
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I (hopefully) improved your code with some pythonic magic. Now it´s a list of tuples and uses automatic tuple-unwrapping.

```
testP = [(4, 230), (7, 96), (1, 0)]

def printPoly2(P):
    for i, e in P:
        if e != 0:
            print("{} x^{} + ".format(i, e))

printPoly2(testP)
```

Prints out

```
4 x^230 + 
7 x^96 +
```

Comment: You still need to print the constant term without `x^0`.

Comment: @chepner I think so too, but that was the original post^^
tani, you maybe should add an else case and just print out the "i"

Answer (score 0):

Just had 5 more minutes... here you go

```
testP = [(4, 230), (7, 96), (1, 0)]

def printPoly2(polynom):
    parts = []
    for i, e in polynom:
        parts.append(_format_polynome(i,e))

    print " + ".join(parts)

def _format_polynome(i, e):
    if e == 0:
        return "{}".format(i)
    else:
        return "{} x^{}".format(i, e)

printPoly2(testP)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would write this code in something I think is a more pythonic way of writting it:

```
def poly2(P):
    result = []
    for item in P:
        n, e = item
        if e == 0:
            result.append("1")
        else:
            result.append("{}x^{}".format(n, e))
    return " + ".join(result)

# 4x^230 + 7x^96 + 1
testP = [(4,230), (7,96), (1,0)]
print poly2(testP)
```

note that its more flexible to return a string representation than to print it directly from the function.